# Create html on the fly using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to build a new html page based on the contents of the part of an existing html page to pass the whole thing to an api.

when I try doing something like:

```
var contents = $('#page-section').html();
var fullPage = $.parseHTML('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="newStyle.css"></head ><body></body></html >').appendTo("body", contents);
```

contents variable is fine, but for fullPage I get an error. The goal is to show the "contents" with the newStyle.css

Is there any other way of achieving this?

The reason I want to do this is to pass the string to a pdf generator.

Comment: What is the goal? It's unclear.  What would you then do with `fullPage`?  Also - troubleshooting 101: **what is the error, specifically?** Errors are very useful, and normally give you excellent hints at what's wrong / needs to be fixed.

Comment: `.appendTo()` does not expect a second parameter. What is expected result of appending an `HTML` `document` to `document.body` of an existing `document`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a simple thing:

```
var fullPage = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style></style><title>Asset Availability Report</title></head><body><div class="asset-availability-report">` + contents + `</div></body></html >`;
```

Answer (score 0):

`.appendTo()` does not expect a second parameter. Concatenate `contents` withing `<body></body>` of `HTML` string. Or use `DOMParser()` to create a `document`.

```
var contents = $('#page-section').html();
var fullPage = `<!DOCTYPE html>
                  <html>
                    <head>
                      <link rel=stylesheet href=newStyle.css>
                    </head>
                    <body>${contents}</body>
                  </html >`;

// do stuff with `fullPage` `HTML` string
```